# Is the dom automatically addressable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

It seems like these two statements produce the same output.

```js
console.log(myId)
console.log(document.getElementById('myId'))
```

```html
<div id="myId">Hello World!</div>
```

Q: Is it safe to use `myId` instead of `document.getElementById('myId')`

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables

Comment: You can't use a dash in the html field name if you do this.